# When I bind a tooltip's content to the content of the parent element, it takes the content out of the parent element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ToggleButton on which I want to have a ToolTip which displays the same content as the button. I can successfully set the ToolTip on the button to use the button's content. The XAML for the ToggleButton instance and the ToolTip is here:

```
<ToggleButton Name="toggleButton" IsTabStop="False"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Template="{StaticResource MultiSelectComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=Content}"
                      >
```

The template for the button is here:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MultiSelectComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"  
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

            <Border Name="arrowBorder" Grid.Column="1" Width="16" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Data="M 0 0 L 7 0 L 3.5 4 Z" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="arrowBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ActiveButtonBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="arrowBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,0" />                
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="arrowBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ActiveButtonBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="arrowBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,0" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

MyToolTip control is bound to the Content property of the parent ToggleButton. The binding works as expected. When you start using the control, the button displays its content as it should:

[image]

However, when you hover over the button to activate the tooltip, the tooltip displays the content and the button loses its content:

[image]

And for the rest of the time you use the control in the application, the button content does not appear, though the tooltip continues to work as intended.

Why would this be happening? I would like to be able to display content in both places simultaneously.

Comment: Post complete combobox template.

Comment: That's interesting, for giggles though what if you just did `ToolTip="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` or if it's literally just display text, which would be rendered in TextBlock anyway just `ToolTip="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`